# Index Match with searches between different dates and values

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, match, formula

I'm trying to complete a lookup against 2 sets of criteria. From the attached, I need to return the Fee in column E, where the search date falls between a From and To Date (Cols A&B) and also where the Property Value falls between a Lower & Upper limit (Cols C&D). I've attached some screenshots to help make this clearer.

The formula I have is in cell K3 (Result table): `{=INDEX($E$2:$E$21,MATCH(1,($A$2:$A$21>=H3)*($B$2:$B$21<=H3)*($C$2:$C$21>=I3)*($D$2:$D$21<=I3)),0)}`

At the moment though, this formula returns the bottom figure on the table (£137.17)....whereas it should return £95 - I'm not sure why it's doing this.

The Raw Data

[image: here]

The Result table

[image: here]

Hopefully that makes sense and someone would be kind enough to help.
Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break down the conditions for your `MATCH`

```
($A$2:$A$21>=H3) * ($B$2:$B$21<=H3) * ($C$2:$C$21>=I3) * ($D$2:$D$21<=I3)
```

First condition: Start Date is On-or-After the Target Date

Second condition: End Date is On-or-Before the Target Date

Third condition: Minimum Value is Less-than-or-Equal-to the Target Value

Fourth condition: Maximum Value is Greater-than-or-Equal-to the Target Value.

We can simplify this to 2 Limits:

```
Start_Date ≥ Target_Date ≥ End_Date
Min_Value ≥ Target_Value ≥ Max_Value
```

You *may* be able to see the issue here, but let's plug some figures in.  First, the Target values from the Results table:

```
Start_Date ≥ {2018-06-18} ≥ End_Date
Min_Value ≥ 80000 ≥ Max_Value
```

Now, the numbers from Row 3 of the Raw Data:

```
{2018-05-21} ≥ {2018-06-18} ≥ {2020-06-02}
50001 ≥ 80000 ≥ 100000
```

Hopefully, you now notice that you got your `>=` and `<=` mixed up!  There is no Date which is both After June 2020 *and* Before May 2018, and there is also no number that is Less than 50,000 *and* Greater than 100,000.

If we swap these over, you get this instead:

```
=INDEX($E$2:$E$21,MATCH(1,($A$2:$A$21<=H3)*($B$2:$B$21>=H3)*($C$2:$C$21<=I3)*($D$2:$D$21>=I3)),0)
```

Of course, this still won't work, because your `INDEX MATCH` is written wrong.  You have this:

```
=INDEX(Range, MATCH(1, Condition), 0)
```

But you *should* have this:

```
=INDEX(Range, Match(1, Condition, 0))
```

Like so:

```
=INDEX($E$2:$E$21, MATCH(1, ($A$2:$A$21<=H3)*($B$2:$B$21>=H3)*($C$2:$C$21<=I3)*($D$2:$D$21>=I3), 0))
```

Ideally though, I would recommend changing stuff like `50001` to `50000`, and just use `<` instead of `<=` (otherwise, `50000.5` will error!)

Comment: That's great! Thanks for this.
 
Yeah - take your point about the 50000.5....but I was just working with the data I had and it was all rounded to whole numbers.
 
Regards
Paul